# Load my C# class library in its own app domain and unload when exception occurs without disturbing third party application

Tags: c#

I am createing plugins using c# class library, which can be loaded into third party application, but i want it to be loaded in its own app domain and unload when exception occurs in my code without affecting third party application process

Here is the scenario, we have a third party application which allows to load plugins. I am creating plugins, which can be loaded into this third party application. but when it loads, by default it loads in its own app domain, but i want my plugin to be loaded in its own app domain with out affecting the third party process when an exception occurs in my plugin..Can you help me with the code to achieve the above requirement?

Comment: Does it not unload when you call your unload code when you catch an exception, or does it cause the 3rd party app to crash?

Comment: Okay, you told us what you want to do. What is the question?

Comment: Here is the scenario, we have a third party application which allows to load plugins. I am creating plugins, which can be loaded into this third party application. but when it loads, by default it loads in its own app domain, but i want my plugin to be loaded in its own app domain with out affecting the third party process when an exception occurs in my plugin..Can you help me with the code to achieve the above requirement

Comment: What have you tried already? What challenges have you encountered with each approach?

Comment: i am trying to google, all that i am getting is how to load a dll into a new app domain, but as i cannot modify third party application code, i want my plugin to be loaded in a different app domain

Answer (score 1):

The host application is what chooses the app domain to load the plugin.  If you don't control the host application, you can't control the app domain you're loaded into.  In theory, the app domain is irrelevant though: code your plugin such that exceptions don't bubble out of your classes, and you'll likely end up with much more durable, much better designed code.

Comment: is there no way to seperate my assembly from the host application without touching the code of the host.. doesnt it not solve by defining new app domain name for my plugin

Comment: In theory, your plugin could create a new app domain, and load a second plugin into it, but that's complexity for complexity's sake.  Code your plugin to not throw exceptions into the host, and you'll be a world better for it.

Comment: yeah i agree..that we need to code in a such a way that all exceptions are handled and shouldnt be thrown, but this is a requirement which i have to implement, if not need to justify with solid reasons.. currently the third party host application calls different webservices and my plugin calls different webservices, by default as it is loaded into default domain, the host application window doesnt loads but waits for my plugin to load first when calling webservices. I want both to act individually

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but my answer doesn't change because your client doesn't understand the technology involved in their requirement.